# cannot use path@version syntax in GOPATH mode

Tags: go

```
> Set-Variable GO111MODULE -Value on
> go get golang.org/x/tools/gopls@latest
go: cannot use path@version syntax in GOPATH mode
```

So far I'm having a thoroughly horrible experience learning Go. It all started when I tried renaming a variable in VS Code. Here's the story.

- I'm learning Go and have written about 10 lines, ever.
- I'm on Windows `:-[` which is proving a hurdle.
- I'm running version 1.13 and I want to start as if Go Modules is all I've ever known.
- I have neither a GOPATH or GOROOT environment variable set.
- Go tooling seems to be in `c:\Go`.
- I downloaded the code for a book I'm reading and opened it in VS Code.
- I have `C:\DATA\go\gopl.io\ch1\fetchall\main.go` open in VS Code, `c:\DATA\go` is where I stick my code.
- VS Code has auto installed a bunch of Go tools to help me.
- I tried to F2 rename a variable in `func main` to something that made more sense to me.
- I encountered

```
Rename failed: gorename: can't find package containing (path to your .go file)
```

The solution to this error, as far as my noob brain understands is that I need to update a package called *packages* or perhaps `gopls` which is the Language Server used by VS Code or something.

So I ran `c:\DATA> go get golang.org/x/tools/gopls@latest` but got an error that seemed to be something to do with new support for the syntax to specifying versions and Go Modules being new or something.

I then read for hours more and found that this has something to do with some `GO111MODULE` variable and what folder I run `go get` from.

Hence I tried setting that variable but it doesn't seem to work.

Note I'm running these commands from `c:\DATA` rather than from where the book sample `main.go` code is, because I'm guessing that this Language Server package is not for that code, but is a thing that VS Code uses, and so its supposed to be "globally" installed somehow, somewhere? But I could be wrong.

As you can see, I haven't faintest idea what I'm doing and well, tbh, its not exactly fun `:(`

### UPDATE

I do have a `GOPATH` set to `c:\DATA\go` but in the VS Code terminal which is PowerShell, when I run `Get-Variable` its not listed, but if I then run `cmd` to enter a normal shell prompt, it is set. Strange.

Comment: Correct. You cannot use `package@version` with `GOPATH`. That is new functionality which is provided by, and requires, Go modules. If you want to use Go's dependency management functionality, use Go modules (start by moving your project outside of your `GOPATH` and then running `go mod init` in the root of your project).

Comment: «I have neither a GOPATH or GOROOT environment variable set.». You should never try to set `GOROOT` by hand, so just forget about it. `GOPATH` is more interesting: since some vertion, Go synthesizes one for you if you do not have one specified explicitly. I beleive it should be `%USERPROFILE%/Go` on Windows but it's easy to check by running `go env` in a console window and looking for what it prints for the value of `GOPATH`.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I don't understand how fixing the rename operation used by VS Code is related to the location of my code?

Comment: It's likely that vscode (or the language server it's using) can't do the rename in a file that is "floating" outside a proper Go module structure.  Check out the docs (https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#quick-start) for how to create a new module from the command line and then open that in vscode.  I agree that "go get" is a nightmare in recent go versions. Hopefully they'll fix it (https://github.com/golang/go/issues/30515)

Comment: @MarkA That was so plausible it was scary ;) alas it didn't work. I renamed a variable in a sample GCP function (with go.mod present) and got the same error Rename failed: gorename: can't find package containing C:\DATA\go\hello\function.go

Comment: @MarkA Thanks, you inspired a rethink.

Answer (score 0):

Okay the problem was that none of my code was in a `src` directory. Once I'd moved it all into `c:\DATA\go\src` it worked.