# Where do I put the code for my own packages in Golang

Tags: go

Assume `GOPATH=c:\DATA\go` and then assume this:

```
C:\
  DATA\
    go\
      bin\
      pkg\
      src\
```

My understanding is that `bin` is for compiled "commands" as the docs phrase it, I assume they mean compiled command line apps.

And `pkg` is for installed packages, each under its parent OS+architecture folder.

And `src` is for my code, each "project" is under a subfolder. I'm not sure if my "project" folders are technically referred to as "repos", "modules" or "packages"? Or any of these, depending on what it is?

My question: If I author my own module or package, i.e. a **reusable** package, then should I keep it under `src` or `pkg`?

The basic Go language is less than a few hours reading, alas the folder conventions have caused me days of head-scratching and tooling errors.

Comment: [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) explains code organization.

Comment: @JimB Thanks but I've read that doc a few times. I've made notes and followed the tutorial. Its omission of the src, pkg or bin folders led to this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60043466/cannot-use-pathversion-syntax-in-gopath-mode/60045264#60045264. This doesn't address my direct question. I've been coding since I was 8, I was a WinNT engineer for Microsoft, I'm 42 now, and if I'm struggling then I'm sure many others are also confused. At some point, teachers at elementary schools will need to teach this stuff to kids, so as a community we need to do a much better job of all this.

Comment: It sounds like you're still trying to use GOPATH, which is very well described in the older version of that doc here: https://golang.org/doc/gopath_code.html. In general you should be using modules now, which means nearly everything under GOPATH is an implementation detail.

Comment: Thanks. "It sounds like you're still trying to use GOPATH" Not intentionally. I don't know what I'm doing. I just want to write a microservice and factor some of my more reusable code into modules. I also want the rename to work. It seems that's a recently fixed thing, like rename didn't work with modules. Perhaps I need to give Golang another couple of years. It seems its in a transition period and perhaps not the right time to start.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how we have been doing it for a few years (which seems to work just fine):

There is a parent directory (name it `src` or something else). This directory contains a list of projects. Each project is its own module (i.e. has its own `go.mod` file).

Because sometimes you would need to share code between projects, we ended up having a project called `shared` which has its own modules that are used by different other projects. Though to be honest, it happened a few times that it was difficult to decide if a module belongs in `project_X` or in `shared`. So you might want to be careful with that.

*EDIT*: Forgot to mention that `cmd` is meant for main applications inside a project and `pkg` is meant for library code that will be used by external applications.

An example tree of such a structure is as follows:

```
src
├── project_1
│   ├── cmd
│   ├── go.mod
│   ├── go.sum
│   └── pkg
├── project_2
│   ├── cmd
│   ├── go.mod
│   ├── go.sum
│   └── pkg
├── shared
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── cmd
│   ├── go.mod
│   ├── go.sum
│   └── pkg
|       ├── pkg_1
|       │   ├── README.md
|       │   ├── fi1e_1.go
|       │   └── fi1e_2.go
|       ├── pkg_2
|       │   ├── README.md
|       │   └── fi1e_1.go
|       ├── pkg_3
|       │   ├── pkg_3_1
|       |   |   ├── file_1.go
|       |   |   └── file_2.go
|       │   ├── pkg_3_2
|       │   └── pkg_3_3
|       └── util
|           ├── README.md
|           ├── common.go
|           └── logger.go
└── tools
    ├── README.md
    ├── go.mod
    ├── go.sum
    ├── tool_1
    ├── tool_2
    └── tool_3
```

Comment: Without questioning that this works, I wouldn't take this as default pattern. The reason is the introduction of Go modules with 1.11 (IIRC).

Comment: @ifnotak Thank you for sharing, that's really clear. I'm also interested in Ulrich's comment as I am starting from a world of Go Modules. However, I see these all have `go.mod` files within.

Comment: @LukePuplett You can check this for reference. https://github.com/golang-standards/project-layout/issues/18